# Loop through an object and display an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know if its possible to loop over an image in a JS object and display it? I have this code so far. At the end you can see that each

element in my object is displayed on the page however i'd like to loop through an image too and display it after the sequence. Is this possible?

I tried to create a function after my set timeout function and then call it within the event listener as logically i though that made sense but no it doesn't work.

```
recipe = {
  coffee: ["Boil some water", "Brew the coffee grounds", "Pour coffee in the cup", "Add sugar and milk"],
  lemonTea: ["Boil some water", "Steep the water in the tea", "Pour tea in the cup", "Add lemon"],
  chocolate: ["Boil some water", "Add drinking chocolate powder to the water", "Pour chocolate in the cup"]
imgUrl: [https://unsplash.com/photos/jn-HaGWe4yw]
}


const lemonTea = document.getElementById("lemon");
const coffee = document.getElementById("coffee");
const chocolate = document.getElementById("chocolate");

lemonTea.addEventListener("click", () => {
 prepareDrink("lemonTea") 
 insertImage()
});

coffee.addEventListener("click", () => { 
prepareDrink("coffee")
});

chocolate.addEventListener("click", () => { 
prepareDrink("chocolate")
});



function prepareDrink(drink) {
  const steps = document.getElementById('steps');
  const selected = recipe[drink];
  // console.log(selected)
  steps.innerHTML = '';
  selected.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
   /* console.log(element,index)*/
   /* printStep(element);*/
   setTimeout( function() {
   steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${element}</li>` )}, 1000 * index);

});

}

  function insertImage(){
   steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend' `imgUrl`)
  }
  insertImagae();
```

Comment: you are referencing `steps` inside the `insertImage` function. That variable is declared inside the `prepareDrink` function and thus out of scope of `insertImage`. Either pass it to insertImage or declare it globally

Comment: Hello I'm not sure how to pass it. I'm new to this. When you say declare it globally you mean place this variable ` const steps = document.getElementById('steps');` outside of the prepareDrink function? If I do that will it work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem you had was that your steps variable wasn't in the scope of the insertImage() function. You don't have to use a setTimeout or call the insertImage function at the end of the script as you did.

Here's a code example of what you could do. I added the steps parameter so you can use it inside the function.

```
recipe = {
  coffee: ["Boil some water", "Brew the coffee grounds", "Pour coffee in the cup", "Add sugar and milk"],
  lemonTea: ["Boil some water", "Steep the water in the tea", "Pour tea in the cup", "Add lemon"],
  chocolate: ["Boil some water", "Add drinking chocolate powder to the water", "Pour chocolate in the cup"]
};

imgUrl = 'https://unsplash.com/photos/jn-HaGWe4yw';

const lemonTea = document.getElementById("lemon");
const coffee = document.getElementById("coffee");
const chocolate = document.getElementById("chocolate");

lemonTea.addEventListener("click", () => {
 prepareDrink("lemonTea")
});

coffee.addEventListener("click", () => { 
prepareDrink("coffee")
});

chocolate.addEventListener("click", () => { 
prepareDrink("chocolate")
});

function prepareDrink(drink) {
  const steps = document.getElementById('steps');
  const selected = recipe[drink];
  steps.innerHTML = '';
  selected.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
   setTimeout( function() {
     steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${element}</li>`);
   }, 1000 * index);

   if (index === array.length - 1) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       insertImage(steps);
     }, 1000 * array.length);
   }
  });
}

function insertImage(steps){
    steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', imgUrl);
}
```

It was unclear to me if you want to show the image or just the image URL, but if you an img tag on your insertAdjacentHTML that should do the work.
Also, if you want loop through images instead of displaying the same image always, you could change your recipe object to something like this:

```
coffee: { instructions: ["Boil some water", "Brew the coffee grounds", "Pour coffee in the cup", "Add sugar and milk"], image: "imgUrl"}
```

And then adapt your functions as this:

```
function prepareDrink(drink) {
  const steps = document.getElementById('steps');
  const selected = recipe[drink].instructions;
  steps.innerHTML = '';
  selected.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${element}</li>`);
  });

  insertImage(steps, image);
}

function insertImage(steps, img){
    steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', img);
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you @pedro i have done what you said but how do I get the image to appear as the 6th step? At the moment the image is added straight away i want it to come as the last step when you click on a button : https://jsfiddle.net/angie11/ywpfjut6/7/

Comment: @AngelaInniss, I edited the answer so you display the image as a last step. 
Check if you're on the last position of your array, then call insertImage() inside a setTimeout().
On your fiddle you use afterend on insertAdjacentHTML. When you do that the img tag is placed as the first element outside your steps element, if you try to clear the steps in prepareDrink() you won't clear the image as well.
To clear the image every time you pick a recipe use beforeend.
More info on insertAdjacentHtml check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#Syntax).

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Now I see that the last step that gets printed is my image - it's the image URL but I will wrap it in <img>tags to get the image to display. Thank you for the explanations and documentation. I will read up on insertAdjacentHtml